# How to dynamically add button in different layout in android?

Tags: android, layout

I want to make a view . Here would be multiple option and one option would have multiple button. Data will retrieve from web-service.  The whole process have to do dynamically.

[image]

My code is here,and  I made like that but i have to do it like image above.

[image]

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_option_selection);
    tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
    int itemId = getIntent().getIntExtra("itemId", 0);
    getGroupName(itemId);
}

private void getGroupName( final int itemId) {
    StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Method.GET,
            getString(R.string.base_url)+"ItemsOptions/GetGroupByItemID?itemID="
                    + itemId, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {                   
                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);


                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                             groupId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getString("GroupName");
                             showOption(itemId,groupId);

                        }
                        //showOption(itemId,groupId);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {

                }
            });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringrequest);

}

protected void showOption(int itemId,String groupName) {
    StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Method.GET,
            getString(R.string.base_url)+"ItemsOptions/GetAllOptionByItemGroupID?itemID="+itemId+"&groupID="+groupName+"", 
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                             String option = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getString("OptionsName");

                             if (i % 3 == 0) {
                                    tableRow = new TableRow(
                                            getApplicationContext());
                                    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                                }

                                orderBtn = new OrderButton(
                                        getApplicationContext());
                                orderBtn.setId(i);
                                orderBtn.setText(option);
                                orderBtn.setTextColor(Color
                                        .parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                                orderBtn.setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.selector));
                                tableRow.addView(orderBtn);
                                orderBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        v.setSelected(true);
                                        enabledButton = orderBtn.getId();
                                        deselectButtons();

                                    }
                                });

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {

                }
            });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringrequest);
```

Comment: paste the link to the image(s), I will make it visible if it's okay.

Comment: search some online tool offering to upload your code or images, such as https://pastelink.net/

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What have you tried so far? Your question is unclear .

Comment: Here i m using TableLayout to add whole view , But i have to separate them in basis of options, just like as image.

Comment: @Faravy : I still don't understand what you want and you haven't posted any code or layout XML. Is the image you've posted the one you have or the one you want to have? Please post at least an image of both and also code and layout XML to show what you've already tried.

Comment: @Squonk Added my code and image what i have made.

Comment: Please change your question from "How to dynamically add button in different layout in android?" which I gave you the answer to " How to dynamically add button in different ACTIVITY in android?"

Answer (score 0):

```
whateverbuttonclicked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

  LinearLayout layoutyouwantbuttonin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutyouwantbuttonin);
  Button brandnewbutton = new Button(NameofActivity.this);
  String bc = whateverbuttonclicked.getText().toString();
  brandnewbutton.setText(bc); 
  layoutyouwantbuttonin.addView(brandnewbutton);

}});
```